# SpriteKit - best way to draw shadow for SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

What is the best way in **iOS7** to achieve a simple shadow effect in iOS's SpriteKit like CALayer's shadow properties.

My SKSpriteNode needs a shadow and it has a specific/complex shape.

Answer (score 1):

Create the same image again, make it black. Add this as child sprite and offset its position slightly.

Note: this is one way, and it works well. There is no *best* way, it's always a trade-off between ease of use/workflow, memory usage, performance and other things.